# How can I split html tr tags in a table using regex in c#?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to successfully split tr elements in a table using regex, Ive tried using

```
@"(?<=<\/tr>)"
```

but it doesn't seem to give me the desired output.

i want my output to be similar to this

```
[0] <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
    </tr>
[1] <tr>
    <td>ccc</td>
    <td>ddd</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/

Comment: The saying is, i had 1 problem and i want to solve it with regex, now i have 2 problems

Comment: If you want to pass html then use a framework that passes html, don't use regex or otherwise you'll be back here every 10 minutes with a new problem

Answer (score -1):

The Regular Expression you are looking for must be something like this: `<tr>.*<\/tr>`.

And the code:
with the following input:

```
var str = @"<table>
<tr><td>aaa</td><td>bbb</td</tr>
<tr><td>ccc</td><td>ddd</td></tr>
</table>";
```

we can write something like this:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(str, @"<tr>.*<\/tr>");
for (var i=0; i < matches.Count; i++)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"[{i}]: {matches[i]}");
}
```

the output:

```
[0]: <tr><td>aaa</td><td>bbb</td</tr>
[1]: <tr><td>ccc</td><td>ddd</td></tr>
```

Comment: I don't that's right, I suspect you'll only find one result as it won't be looking for the first instance of </tr>